# Joomla BaseURL in Article

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla2.5

got a question
does anyone know a **Joomla Plugin** to get my site's **BaseURL** in **Article Manager**?
since I'm working in `http://localhost/project`, I need to avoid some file directory conflict when uploading the site to the hosting

thanks

Comment: If you are using TinyMCE change the plugin settings to relative urls.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any such plugins: but I don't think you need it.

Joomla uses relative paths so if just insert relative paths or even better use non-sef paths (i.e. index.php?option=com_content etc.) in your article text links, it will work automatically.

However, if you have already used hardcoded paths, or you chose to use "external url" menu items with the full path (i.e. starting with a single "/") then just run a find/replace on your sql dump before reimporting, it only takes a minute and it will catch all occurrences.